# Calculate monthly balance in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Data-Table:** 
[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b1L48d9w)

```
CREATE TABLE vouchers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    credits_collected INT,
    credits_redeemed INT
);

INSERT INTO vouchers
(event_date, credits_collected, credits_redeemed
)
VALUES 
('2020-01-08', '900', '700'),
('2020-02-15', '500', '300'),
('2020-02-20', '100', '250'),
('2020-03-19', '600', '850'),
('2020-04-03', '450', '130');
```

---

**SQL-Query:**

```
SELECT
t1.event_month AS event_month,
t1.credits_collected AS credits_collected,
t1.credits_redeemed AS credits_redeemed,
SUM(t1.credits_collected - t1.credits_redeemed) OVER (
ORDER BY t1.event_month ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS balance
FROM

  (SELECT
  DATE_PART('month', v.event_date) AS event_month,
  SUM(v.credits_collected) AS credits_collected,
  SUM(v.credits_redeemed) AS credits_redeemed
  FROM vouchers v
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1) t1

GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

**Result:**

```
event_month  |  credits_collected  |  credits_redeemed  |  balance
-------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------
    1        |        900          |       700          |     200
    2        |        600          |       550          |     250
    3        |        600          |       850          |       0
    4        |        450          |       130          |     320
```

---

I am loading the above `data-table` into PowerBI. 
Now, I want to create a report that looks like the results I am getting with the SQL-Query above.

I am able to put `credits_collected` and `credits_redeemed` to the report. 
However, I have no clue what DAX formula I need to calculated the balance for the end of each month.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue with two steps:

**Step 1:** Implementing an additional column with this DAX formula:

```
column_balance_calculated_daily = CALCULATE(SUM(Tabelle1[credits_collected])-SUM(Tabelle1[credits_redeemed]),ALL('Tabelle1'),'Tabelle1'[event_date]<=EARLIER('Tabelle1'[event_date] ))
```

**Step 2:** Use the column in the following DAX formula:

```
balance = CALCULATE(MAX(Tabelle1[column_balance_calculated_daily]),ENDOFMONTH(Tabelle1[event_date]))
```