# Calculating Monthly Variations Between Non-Consecutive Dates in PowerBI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Based on this table:

| Carteira | 30/11/23 | 29/12/23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juros I |  |  |
| Pós-f | 1569 | 1717 |
| Pré-f | 952 | 925 |
| Risco C |  |  |
| Global | 1196 | 1014 |

My goal is to add a third column indicating the variation between the values for different dates. However, the challenge is that the dates are part of the same column, and I need to calculate variations between non-immediately consecutive dates. For instance, between 30/Nov and 29/Dec, there are data points from 21/Dec, and in this case, I'm looking to calculate a monthly variation.

Is there a visualization, DAX or powerquery function to help me out?

I tried the sollution propodes in the question "[Calculate monthly balance in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75207527/calculate-monthly-balance-in-powerbi)", but then I had an issue.

This would be my code:

```
column_calculated =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(DRM[VL_MTM_Ativo])- SUM(DRM[VL_MTM_Passivo]),
    ALL('DRM'),
    'DRM'[DATAREF] <= EARLIER('DRM'[DATAREF] )
    )
```

But I get an error message, stating that "EARLIER/EARLIEST references a previous row context that does not exist". But `'DRM'[DATAREF]` seems regular to me, as a date column. I did not receive this error message with common functions like `MAX`.

Comment: Have a look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624201/ , in particular the `TOPN(1, ... )`. Hopefully that will help demonstrate how to get the pervious  date. If you need more, add your data table as a markdown table to your question, along with any code you have tried or are struggling with.

Comment: I edited the question in order to get the table in markdown. Here's the code: | Carteira | 30/11/23 | 29/12/23 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| Juros I| | |
|   Pós-f| |1717|
|   Pré-f|952 |925 |
| Risco C| | |
|   Global| |1196|1014|

Comment: Tried it but could not make it work. I updated the question considerind this.

Comment: Please update your question with a markdown table of your data table and not that of a visual/matrix. For example, are the two dates in different columns or the one column?